# how to install OWLCPP in Linux?

Tags: c++, boost, owl, boost-build

I'm totally new to `boost.build`. I need to load an `.owl` file in Linux which means I have to (maybe?) install a library---owlcpp.

I followed the instructions from the owlcpp tutorial to install it. But at last step which is `b2 release`, there is an error:

> Unable to load Boost.Build: could not find build system.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'd use the `b2` from the boost distribution. If you built boost from source, it'll be in the top level directory. I've not tried to get all the other dependencies of `owlcpp` (man, they need better docs)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I meet a strange problem. When I finished the installation steps and tried to run "b2 release", it came out :  b2: command not found...

Comment: Where is it built/installed? Even if it's in the current directory, you'd need to say `./b2`

Comment: thank you.sehe. I have solved this problem. I forgot add PATH.